# How does JOIN work even when there isn't any matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query:

```
UPDATE users u 
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.author_id = u.id
SET u.events = 0, e.seen = 1
WHERE  u.id = ?
```

My query updates `users` table even when this condition `... ON e.author_id = u.id` doesn't match any row. Now I need to also update `events` when there isn't any matched row in `users` table. I can do that by `RIGHT JOIN`. But I want to know can I mix both `RIGHT JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` together?

Comment: Not sure about MYSQL has it but full outer join

Comment: I never thought of doing a *LEFT* join with an update. That would seem dangerous. Looks like you found out why.

Comment: I must say stack I love your questions. They have become nearly famous in my mind over the last 2 or 3 months :p

Comment: @Drew Why?? :-)

Comment: idk, they have this certain angle to them. Like, hm, I never thought of doing it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in MySQL, because MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

But why not just run two update statements:

```
UPDATE users u 
    SET u.events = 0
    WHERE  u.id = ?;

UPDATE events e 
    e.seen = 1
    WHERE e.author_id = ?;
```

You can wrap these in a transaction, if you think the transactional semantics are important and your storage engine supports transactions.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. Just what about `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: @stack . . . `CROSS JOIN` will fail unless the id is in both tables.